# Bot Framework: How to make an OpenUrl button on a herocard in Kik

Tags: c#, botframework, kik

I am trying to use the `ActionTypes.OpenUrl` type on a `CardAction` in a hero card on kik.  all it does is echo back the message.  It does not actually open a URL.  I have the same code working on multiple channels, but cannot get it working on kik.  Has anyone been able to find a work around for this?

Here is the code I am using:

```
Activity reply = activity.CreateReply();
var card = new HeroCard
{
    Title = "title",
    Text = "text",
    Buttons = new List<CardAction> {new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl,"url 1", text: "open url 1", value:@"https://www.google.com/"),
        new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl,title:"url 2", text: "open url 2", value:@"https://www.google.com/"),
        new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl,title:"url 3", text: "open url 3", value:@"https://www.google.com/")
    }
};
reply.Attachments.Add(card.ToAttachment());
await context.PostAsync(reply);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunately not going to work for you.  In order to display "Hero Cards" in kik Bot Framework has to use [keyboards](https://dev.kik.com/#/docs/messaging#keyboards) specifically, the **Suggested Response Keyboard** which does not support an open url type.  According to their documentation: "The type of response to send. Must be one of: `text`, `friend-picker`, `picture`". So there is no way to actually open a URL from a button in a herocard on kik.